# Error in SQL Server stored procedure, timeout period elapsed

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to use a stored procedure in which I am sending single parameter which I sent through ADO.NET C# code.

Now the problem is the stored procedure is getting called from my dev environment and when I deploy it to production I am getting exception of **timeout elapse** and it never reaches to the stored procedure (I have added logs to check if stored procedure is actually hit and at what stage it causes timeout).

> Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>   at ProjectName.ViewModel.ClassViewModel.<>c__DisplayClasse.b__d()

I have no clue what is happening over production server. Please guide me over this issue.

There are a lot of questions for same error message but I am not able to find similar scenario for issue, like stored procedure not getting executed and still it causes timeout error.

I would have included stored procedure but it is very basic stored procedure.

Please help :)

Thanks,
Nikhil Chavan.

Comment: try to run stored procedure directly without using your application and then  try to find out what is going out wrong by commenting different parts of query mean to say which one is taking long time to run on server

Comment: Stored procedure runs if I execute it from sql server management studio and it hardly takes 3-4 secs. The problem is stored procedure is not executed at all when I am trying to use it with ADO.NET code.

Comment: try using this connection string DataSource=server;InitialCatalog=databaseUserId=username;Password=password;Connect Timeout=0, 0 means for unlimited time out

Comment: @rashfmnb this will just hang the application forever if an attempt is made to connect to the wrong server

Comment: Yes, I can't risk on production server.... Sorry I can't set infinite Timeout :)

Comment: i am suggesting this only for checking purpose in the end you have to modify the code or the query to make the things work in the optimized way.

Comment: From @nouman: Have you tried to run your stored procedure in SQLServer and check if it runs successfully?

Have you tried setting the SqlCommand.CommandTimeout Property?

Have you checked your connection string if it is pointing to the correct DB and it is reachable?

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. I figured it out there was issue with stored procedure getting timed out in one user defined function on production server database and it was SqlTransaction which was doing rollback if transaction got any errors. So in my case there was a timeout issue but due to rollback in transaction it was behaving like stored procedure was never getting called.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to run your stored procedure in SQLServer and check if it runs successfully?

Have you tried setting the SqlCommand.CommandTimeout Property?

Have you checked your connection string if it is pointing to the correct DB and it is reachable?

Comment: All these should be comments.

Comment: yeah i know but currently not allowed to add comments.

Comment: Then wait until you can. There is a reason people need enough rep before they can post comments. There is even a canned answer for such cases!

Comment: Thanks @Nouman got the solution by preventing SqlTransaction rollback code and see where stored procedure is timing out and taking long to process.